# Differentiation on tangent on a point

Tags: derivatives, slope

> $$\text{tangent of } e^{x^2} + \ln x + e^{x\ln x}$$

How to find the tangent of this curve at $(1, e+1)$ and differentiate it?

Comment: Differentiate and substitute to find the slope.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your questions

Comment: To differentiate this function, use the chain rule for derivatives.

Comment: how to differentiate e^x^2?

Comment: Let $u=x^2$. Use $\dfrac {d(e^{x^2})}{dx} = \dfrac {d (e^u)}{du} \cdot \dfrac {du}{dx}$.

Comment: may i know the result after differentiating it please?

Comment: is it =2xe^x^2?

Comment: Yes you're right. You can type the expression into WolframAlpha to check.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=e^{x^2}+\ln x+e^{x\ln x}$.

Using the fact that $e^{\ln x}=x$, we have
$$y=e^{x^2}+\ln x+x^x$$

Let us suppose for simplicity, $u=e^{x^2}$, $v=\ln x$ and $w=x^x$.
$$y=u+v+w$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{dw}{dx}\quad (*)$$

**Differentiating $u$**

To differentiate $u=e^{x^2}$, we let $t=x^2$.
By Chain Rule,
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dt}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^t)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=2xe^{x^2}\quad (1)$$

**Differentiating $v$** is trivial as we know $(\ln x)'=1/x$. So,
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\quad (2)$$

**Differentiating $w$**

For this, take $\ln$ of both sides
$$\ln w =x\ln x$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$,
$$\frac{1}{w}\cdot\frac{dw}{dx}=x\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\ln x\cdot 1$$
$$\frac{1}{x^x}\cdot \frac{dw}{dx}=1+\ln x$$
$$\frac{dw}{dx}=x^x(1+\ln x)\quad (3)$$

Using $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(*)$, we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2xe^{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+x^x(1+\ln x)$$

**Thus** the slope of $y$ at the point $(1,e+1)$ is obtained by putting $x=1$,
$$\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]_{x=1}=2e+1+1=2e+2$$

Thus, the tangent has slope $m=2e+2$ and lies on $(x_0,y_0)=(1, e+1)$. By point-slope form,
$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$
So, the equation of required tangent is
$$y-e-1=(2e+2)(x-1)$$
$$(2e+2)x-y-(e-1)=0$$

Hope this helps :)